# What is the proper way of writing a global config file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a config file so that any other .py files with this config imported will be able to access the variables inside it.

Now I also want to modify some of those variables in a main.py according to the input parameters of argparse. However, I don't know how to make the modification also work for other files.

For example, in `config.py`:

```py
VariableA = 5
```

in `func.py`:

```py
import config

def display():
    print(config.VariableA)
```

in `main.py`:

```py
import config
from func import display
config.VariableA = 10
display()  # 5
```

The output will be `5` instead of 10. How could I modify the variables in config.py so that it works for the rest of scripts?

I tried to define a class and set the variables to be the static variables of this class, such as:

```py
class Config:
    VariableA = 5

Config.VariableA = 10
```

and this did work. But I don't know if this solution is the most proper way?

Comment: Are the other .py files executed by the same python process?

Comment: If you want something persistent you could use a json file or use an actual config file maybe with `configparser`

Comment: According to your question title, you can refer [4 Ways to manage the configuration in Python](https://hackernoon.com/4-ways-to-manage-the-configuration-in-python-4623049e841b) article to get more understand about handling configuration files in python.

Answer (score 0):

What you asked actually works if you run your other scripts from main (by using imports  that is), and you always qualify the settings accesses with `config.`. If you start other scripts separately they don't share the same namespace of main and so you have to persist the settings and read them from disk, or environment.